# how to pass php variables to javascript map function

Tags: javascript, php

Just want to pass php variables $x and $y to javascript map function (as lat and long). Please help.
Here is my controller:

```
<?php
$x = 25.114667;
$y = 55.137797;
?>
```

Here is my JS file:

```
function initialize()
    {
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
    var mapOptions = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:12,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
      ,mapOptions);

    }   google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('showhidemap'), 'click', initialize);
```

Comment: Try to debug you code-> `alert(lat)` below the `var long = "<?php echo $y; ?>";`  and see value is coming or not.

Comment: the alert message was <?php echo $y; ?>

Comment: the alert message was <?php echo 'can i see that?'; ?>

Comment: the javascript code is in external file. Can it be a problem?

Comment: Ok, you can't run PHP it seems.. I suspect this is a plain .js file, you need to execute your php echos inside a php file, which will product a javascript object, then use this object in the .js file.

Comment: @vlzvl i thinks OP seeing this in his editor without running the php script.

Comment: could you help me to do that?

Comment: @TProDeveloper, to get any more help you'll need to provide more information, like the hierarchy of your files, what calls what. What extension has the file the above fragment lives in? When it gets called (where is its `<script src= line in the .php you need to give)`. Update the question with more information, preferrable copy/paste of your files (the important parts).

Comment: @vlzvl Do you know, how to create json, pass it to external javascript file and then parse it?

Answer (score 2):

you are passing string in you js variable `lat` and `long`. assign value directly as float
try this

```
 var lat = <?php echo $x; ?>;
 var long = <?php echo $y; ?>;
```

also must include the script with google map key on above of google map initialization.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_MAP_KEY&sensor=true"> </script>
```

**GOOGLE MAP KEY :** must be generate for your site.

see some urls might help you

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map
https://developers.google.com/maps/signup?csw=1
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: I have already tried in that way. Codeigniter shows syntax errors.

Comment: what kind of syntax error? show me. may be syntax error for another reason.

Comment: I took a printscreen of the error. Please advise how can I send it to you.

Comment: @TProDeveloper update your question with that image.

Comment: I just did it. Please have a look.

Comment: i think that is your editor warnings.  try to run the code on browser then see it.

Comment: I did it. The same issue.

Comment: what problem show in you browser when you run this php file?

Comment: have you run this php script in browser like firefox, crome or IE ?

Comment: and what is displaying in that ?

Comment: there are no any errors, it shows the map div box but there is no map in it because javascript does not recognize php variables

Comment: so your problem is that map is not showing ? have you include the GOOGLE MAP KEY url in your file.? like `<script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_MAP_KEY&sensor=true">
    </script>`

Comment: I just added the image of map to my question. There are no any problems with map. because it was working fine without passing php variables that is why I did not include the key part in my question.

Comment: your page is showing google map. cordinates may be wrong. try to reduce zoom level also. `zoom:5,`

Comment: try with `$x = 22.7367856;
$y = 79.2196445;` and `zoom:5`

Comment: I changed the zoom to 5, it still does not work. The problem is not with map, the problem is that javascript does not recognize php variables $x and $y.

Comment: if js not recognize your php variables then map will not show. have you tried with my given cordinates.

Comment: @Satish Sharma, Googlemaps v3 doesn't need an api key. OP needs to provide some information to the PHP file so to create a JSON object there (giving the lang/lat there), which will be visible to JS file afterthat. With only the .JS file this can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add

```
$x = 25.114667;
$y = 55.137797;
```

to some tag like

```
<div data-lat="<?php echo $y; ?>" data-long="<?php echo $y; ?>" id="showhidemap">show map</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Javascript object *in your .php* file, **just before your include your javascript file** (the one containing the above fragment), which will be filled by your longitude/latitude information.
Like this:

**YOUR PHP FILE**

```
<html>
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var mapLangLat = {
         long:<?php echo $x; ?>,
         lati:<?php echo $y; ?>
      };
   </script>
   <script src="my_remote_script.js"></script>
   ...
```

**YOUR JAVASCRIPT FILE**

```
<script>
function initialize()
    {

    var lat = window.mapLangLat.lati;
    var long = window.mapLangLat.long;

    ...
```

It's required to *find the PHP part* above to be able to code that little javascript object.